# How to make Crystal Reports multilingual?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to make rpt files that are part of an ASP.NET application and are currently only in one language to show in different languages depending on user's local language settings.

I know that this has earlier been done in our company by passing the locale information from C# to main reports, replacing labels by formula fields that return different text depending on the language, linking the locale information parameter to all subreports, replacing all the labels by formula fields in them as well and so on and it does work but I wonder if there is a simpler solution available? Every report consists of pretty many subreports so there is a lot of manual work to do if this is the only way. And of course also lot of risks with all the if clauses, copying the original texts from labels to formula fields etc - easy to copy wrong and then miss it.

There are also a lot of elements that are same in every report, like all the page footers, so creating Formula Fields and replacing labels by them in every page footer separately seems like a lot of work instead of maybe being able to do it just once and apply to all the reports?

Answer (score 0):

A table in a database.  Column names are languages.  Primary key is the majority language of your staff.  Write reports using your main language, but fetch translations from the table on the fly.

The maintenance issue shifts from phrases and words scattered throughout the reports library, with lots of duplicates, to having them all in a single table with no duplicates.

There is the challenge as it gets bigger of avoiding "almost duplicates," e.g., "Total charged" vs. "Total billed" or "Payment" vs. "Amount Paid"  There̓s also the problem that some languages have noun declensions, verb conjugations, different ways of doing plurals, etc.  Without each instance being done by a human who is fluent in the output language, there will always be weird sounding things.  In fact, some native speakers can translate into things they would never say themselves.

But there are tricks to reduce these problems.  For example, you could create a stored procedure to do printf style substitutions.  This allows for word order variations.  One language might put a variable at the end of a sentence while another puts it in the middle.

Two similar approaches are the [GNU gettext utilities](http://www.google.com/search?q=PO%20files) or the way Mac OS does internationalization.